# best way to parse text based log files

Tags: parsing, text

I have these relatively big log files which are generated from a machine via a serial connection.

This log isn`t structured and I need to check various different things. I wonder if there is some kind of existing language or tool which is specialized in this kind of thing?

languages I currently know:
c and c++
python
some java
various scripting language

I hope some of you have a good recomendationt!

Answer (score 0):

Going with what you already know, Just use regular expressions in python.